# What is the simplest analog circuit for integer addition modular 2?

Tags: switches, analog

This probably is a rudimentary question. I would like to have a simple analog (switch) circuit for addition modular 2, or \$a_1+a_2+\cdots +a_n \$ (mod 2). Certainly, digital transistors can accomplish this, but I would prefer analog devices if the circuit is simpler. In practical terms, I would like to design a switch circuit to control a light, where fixing all other switches, any one of them can switch the light on and off. For \$n=2\$ or 2 switches, someone earlier has already suggested using two back to back single-pole-double-throw switches.

Comment: May not be the simplest, but implementing *n* input xor gate using transistors is a solution.

Comment: @nidhin, yes, but I would prefer simpler analog circuit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For 4 places see below: -

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ffXWwk.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

For 3 places remove one of the two pole switches. For more than 4 just keep repeating the 2 pole switches.

Comment: Dang it. I just spent an hour noodling on this and just came up with this. Congrats for beating me to it. At least I have the satisfaction of solving this interesting house wiring issue. Btw, was this a well known design you've known for years or did you just come up with this? +1

Comment: @horta - well done for figuring it out dude but on this occasion knowledge has beaten intelligence LOL